# System.IO.FileNotFoundException thrown by NUnit Test Runner

Tags: c#, .net, nunit, coded-ui-tests, nunit-console

I was able to build with NAnt and run the assembly through NAnt. Now I tried to run my selenium test suit from NUnit command line. I am not even sure if this can be accomplished through NUnit command line. Can anyone please help me to resolve the problem?
Here is the exception trace

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException...

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveType(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, IntPtr* typeInstArgs, Int32 typeInstCount, IntPtr* methodInstArgs, Int32 methodInstCount, ObjectHandleOnStack type)
   at System.ModuleHandle.ResolveTypeHandleInternal(RuntimeModule module, Int32 typeToken, RuntimeTypeHandle[] typeInstantiationContext, RuntimeTypeHandle[] methodInstantiationContext)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.ResolveType(Int32 metadataToken, Type[] genericTypeArguments, Type[] genericMethodArguments)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.FilterCustomAttributeRecord(CustomAttributeRecord caRecord, MetadataImport scope, Assembly& lastAptcaOkAssembly, RuntimeModule decoratedModule, MetadataToken decoratedToken, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, Object[] attributes, IList derivedAttributes, RuntimeType& attributeType, IRuntimeMethodInfo& ctor, Boolean& ctorHasParameters, Boolean& isVarArg)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeModule decoratedModule, Int32 decoratedMetadataToken, Int32 pcaCount, RuntimeType attributeFilterType, Boolean mustBeInheritable, IList derivedAttributes, Boolean isDecoratedTargetSecurityTransparent)
   at System.Reflection.CustomAttribute.GetCustomAttributes(RuntimeType type, RuntimeType caType, Boolean inherit)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetCustomAttributes(Type attributeType, Boolean inherit)
   at NUnit.Core.CoreExtensions.InstallAdhocExtensions(Assembly assembly)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Load(String path)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.Builders.TestAssemblyBuilder.Build(String assemblyName, String testName, Boolean autoSuites)
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.BuildSingleAssembly(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.TestSuiteBuilder.Build(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.SimpleTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.RemoteTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestDomain.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.RemoteTestAgent.AgentRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg)

Exception rethrown at [1]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at NUnit.Core.TestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Core.ProxyTestRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.ProcessRunner.Load(TestPackage package)
   at NUnit.Util.TestLoader.LoadTest(String testName)
```

**EDIT: ADD log from Fusion Log viewer**

```
Assembly Binder Log Entry  (12/9/2014 @ 8:35:42 PM)
The operation was successful.
Bind result: hr = 0x0. The operation completed successfully.

Assembly manager loaded from:  D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  D:\Users\Saifur\Desktop\NUnit-2.6.3\bin\nunit-agent-x86.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = System.EnterpriseServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///D:/Users/Saifur/Desktop/NUnit-2.6.3/bin/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
LOG: Dynamic Base = NULL
LOG: Cache Base = NULL
LOG: AppName = nunit-agent-x86.exe
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: D:\Users\Saifur\Desktop\NUnit-2.6.3\bin\nunit-agent-x86.exe.Config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Found assembly by looking in the GAC.
LOG: Binding succeeds. Returns assembly from D:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\System.EnterpriseServices\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.EnterpriseServices.dll.
LOG: Assembly is loaded in default load context.
```

[image]

Comment: Turn on Fusion Logging and figure out what it is looking for and what it thinks it is missing.  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsUsingFusionLogViewerToDebugObscureLoaderErrors.aspx

Comment: @JohnKoerner thanks for mentioning `Fusion Log Viewer`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Fusion Logging` kind of help me track down the issue. The issue was I was using targeting the wrong assembly as a result it was not finding all dependencies correctly and throwing false alert.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error message due to wrong version I used. nunit.exe is the 64bit version.